# How to setup a centralized state for a mapbox map in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, mapbox-gl-js, vuejs2, vuex

I just started using vuex with vue. I do (roughly) understand the docs. I have a specific issue for which I am not sure whether I should use vuex and if so how to go about.

I have an app in which mapbox map(s) are omnipresent in various layouts and components etc. As I will be making several vue single file components but are working with one same instance of a mapbox map I think it makes sense to have the mapbox map initiated and managed in the vuex store. So e.g. when I change the map layout or something else, it will be reflected in all components.

When I continue in this direction I am puzzled by a couple of things:

1. The map is not just a variable/ array, but an instance of the mapbox class map. So I suppose the initial state is an empty object and then it needs to be initialized. Correct?
2. The initialization is asynchronous and can only happen after the page is loaded, I suppose. That might be why my code below is not working!?

I tried  following:

Made a mapboxmap module, with

**mapboxmap.js**

```
import simple from '../../components/simplestyle'
let mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')

// initial state
const state = {
  myMap: {},
  mapLoaded: false
}

const mutations = {
  loadMap (state, myMap) {
    state.myMap = myMap
    state.mapLoaded = true
  }
}

const actions = {
  loadMap (context) {
    'use strict'
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mysecretmapboxcode'
    let myMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: simple,
      hash: true,
      center: [-74.0073, 40.7124],
      zoom: 16
    })
    context.commit('loadMap', myMap)
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

And as component:

**Maplayout.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id='map' class='map'>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script type='text/babel'>
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.computed.myMapForView.set().then(() => this.computed.myMapForView.get())
  },
  computed: {
    myMapForView: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.myMap
      },
      // setter
      set: function () {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadMap')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Which does not work. Any suggestions on the solution approach and specific way to do this is much appreciated.

Error message I get in the browser:

```
vue.runtime.common.js?d43f:433 TypeError: Cannot read property 'myMapForView' of undefined
    at VueComponent.mounted (eval at 162 (0.ce2d9bf….js:21), <anonymous>:8:18)
    at callHook (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2335:19)
    at Object.insert (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2525:5)
    at invokeInsertHook (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:4352:28)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:4508:5)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2222:19)
    at VueComponent.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2189:10)
    at Watcher.get (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:1652:27)
    at Watcher.run (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:1721:22)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:1539:13)
logError @ vue.runtime.common.js?d43f:433
```

EDIT:
After changing to `this.myMapForView` from `this.computed.myMapForView` I got following errormessage in browser:

```
vue.runtime.common.js?d43f:433 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at VueComponent.mounted (eval at 162 (0.85b2be9….js:21), <anonymous>:6:22)
    at callHook (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2335:19)
    at Object.insert (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2525:5)
    at invokeInsertHook (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:4352:28)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:4508:5)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2222:19)
    at VueComponent.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:2189:10)
    at Watcher.get (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:1652:27)
    at Watcher.run (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:1721:22)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:794), <anonymous>:1539:13)
logError @ vue.runtime.common.js?d43f:433
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me is `new mapboxgl.Map()` is an asynchronous function and in [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) [Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) can contain arbitrary asynchronous operations not mutations not from [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html). **mutation handler functions must be synchronous.**

So you should do `new mapboxgl.Map()` in actions like following:

```
import simple from '../../components/simplestyle'
let mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')

// initial state
const state = {
  myMap: {},
  mapLoaded: false
}

const mutations = {
  loadMap (state, myMap) {
    state.myMap = myMap
  }
}

const actions = {
  loadMap (context) {
    'use strict'
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mysecretmapboxkey'
    var myMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: simple,
      hash: true,
      center: [-74.0073, 40.7124],
      zoom: 16
    })
    context.commit('loadMap', myMap)
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

---

**Edit**:

Given your mouse interactions are causing change in the state, you can have a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?redirect=true#Computed-Properties) in you vue instance with [getter and setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html?redirect=true#Computed-Setter), like following:

```
computed: {
  myMapForView: {
    // getter
    get: function () {
      return this.$store.state. myMap
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newMap) {
      this.$store.commit('loadMap', newMap)
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Working Fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/aucqteLn/

Also check: [Vuex store with "strict: true" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388113/vuex-store-with-strict-true-does-not-work)

Comment: Thanks. Good point. I edited my question including your comments. Still does not work (does not show a map in the browser) though. I will include errormessage I got.

Comment: @musicformellons What it seems is, you are changing the vuex store state somewhere, as it is stated, vuex variables can only be changed via mutations. Can you added the code related to watcher.

Comment: I do not think I am changing the vuex store state from somewhere else in my code... It looks like the mapobject is there but it does not show the tiles.  When I interact with my mouse on the mapcanvas I do get similar errormessage in the browser, so my impression now is that my interaction events with the map (loading, move-end, mouse-click, etc.), all are considered 'changing the vuex state' without using mutations or actions, which makes sense as the state.map object is altered I suppose. Does this make sense? And how to proceed?!

Comment: I made some changes... See edited code and errormessage. We need to dispatch, not commit, right?! I also left out the newMap parameter for the function as our map will be myMap, right?!

Comment: @musicformellons You just need to do `this.myMapForView`

not 

`this.computed.myMapForView`.

Comment: Changed that and got new errormessage, see EDIT above.

Comment: After setting `strict: false` your (unedited) code actually works and the map shows. Will post another question on how to get it working with `strict: true`