# How to keep a vue.js single file component loaded in the background?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I currently have a (geographical) map with points/ markers on it in a vue single file component. When showing details of a point/marker I now use a modal which 'sits on top' of the map component. When I close the modal the map has not reloaded and everything is in the same state, which is as required.

I would prefer not to use a modal but another vue component, but then when going back to the map it reloads and it has lost its state. Is there an easy way to keep the map loaded in the background? So also when going back with 'history' it is still in the same state?

Comment: Aren't [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308177/how-to-setup-a-centralized-state-for-a-mapbox-map-in-vuex) using Vuex?

Comment: @Saurabh Good point! But [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388113/vuex-store-with-strict-true-does-not-work) convinced me that you should not save the entire map in vuex. Working with getters and setters would be quite hard as my map component has a 'complicated state'. Therefore simply keeping it in the background would work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the keep-alive component to keep the component alive when you navigate to a different route. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive

Another option would be to save the state of your component to a store like Vuex, where it is globally available so it stores the data when you navigate away.

Comment: Mmmh, when I wrap my maplayout component with keep-alive and then navigate to another page, and then go-back it lost state... Looks like it is more for toggling the component then for navigating to other components etc.

Comment: Got it working now, haha. Had to add name to component and used 'include' as stated in docs!