# Store Mapbox in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, nuxt.js

While I was trying to store a MapBox instance in Vuex Store, I start getting this error: `"Self is not defined"`. I followed these instructions [How to setup a centralized state for a mapbox map in Vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308177/how-to-setup-a-centralized-state-for-a-mapbox-map-in-vuex), but didn't help. I don't know what's wrong!

here's my code:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
/* -----------------------
*   Action
* ------------------------ */
export default {
  initMap({commit}) {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mysecretmapboxkey'
    const myMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [-74.0073, 40.7124],
      zoom: 16
    })
  commit('setMap', myMap)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this your complete file? It's currently missing a closing } at the end..

Comment: Not This isn't the complete file. I haven't missed anything. When I comment the codes inside the initMap function, everything works fine.